# Centering tikz node text

Tags: tikz-pgf

How node text can be positioned at exact center in the following piece of code?

```
\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) -- (6.1,3.1) node[above=1mm,rotate=-45] {$x$};
```

I want x to appear exactly above and at the center of the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) -- node[above=1mm,sloped] {$x$} (6.1,3.1) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To my taste the `x` is to far from line. I would omit additional distance at `above`.

The same results you can achieved with:

- `\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) to node[above,sloped] {$x$} (6.1,3.1);`
- `\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) -- (6.1,3.1) node[pos=0.5,above,sloped] {$x$};`
- `\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) -- (6.1,3.1) node[midway,above,sloped] {$x$};`

Option `sloped´ automatically rotate text such that it align with line slope.

Comment: You could mention `\draw[dashed] (4.1,5.1) -- (6.1,3.1) node[above=1mm,sloped,pos=0.5] {$x$};` as a second option.

Comment: Y@TorbjørnT, yes, you have right. The same can be also achieved width `midway` option. I will edit my answer.